# How can I get repeat 1 and still skip to next song when clicking next

Tags: iphone, music

In previous IOS (7), I could have a playlist, shuffle to play the first song, then hit repeat one track and listen to the same music as long as I wanted. When I want another song, I could just hit next and the next song will play in a loop (as it's repeat one) until I ask to play the next song. This was perfect.

Now in IOS 9, if I repeat one, then playing next will play the same song from start again. This is useless. I want to switch to the next song in the list and then loop that song.

I command my music from my headphones when I'm motorbiking, double tap used to play next song, that was perfect, no need to fiddle with the iphone, it stays in the pocket.

How to get this behavior back???

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is probably "You can't." The music app changes so often with little rhyme or reason, and the best you can probably do is request Apple bring it back.

Comment: Where? How? to request this. Is there a better music app that just do that? Not interested in streaming solution like spotify and such

Comment: [www.apple.com/feedback/](http://www.apple.com/feedback/). Not sure about another app. Try [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Found 'Beat - Music player' from MonkeyBits, works great. Has strange controls but it's a great replacement to the rubbish apple music app (asking you on each screen to register to their music program).

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/beat-music-player/id605037069?mt=8